# Login validation with arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a multi login with an array, but it is not recognizing my array values.

Also, I want to set a limit of times on which you can try before it gives you a promt

```
let entryCount = 1
let entryLimit = 3
let error = false

let validarCuentas = [{name:"Emilio",password:"abc123"},{name:"Andrea",password:"abc321"},{name:"Hugo", password:"contraseña"}];
    
    // Login con intentos
    function login() {
        response
        user = document.getElementById('user');
        pass = document.getElementById('pass');
        bal = document.getElementById ('bal');
        let userExists = false
        bal = 0
        
        for (i = 0; i < validarCuentas.length; i++){
            if (user.value === validarCuentas[i].name && pass.value === validarCuentas[i].password){
                userExists = true;
                localStorage.setItem('user', user.value)
                localStorage.setItem('pass', pass.value)
                localStorage.setItem('bal', bal.value)
                window.location.href = "cajero.html"
            } else{
                if (entryCount < entryLimit)  {
                    entryCount++
                    alert('Contraseña o usuario invalido, intentelo nuevamente')
                } else {
                    alert('Pasaste el limite de intentos')
                    window.location.href = "index.html"
                } 
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Your code has error. Remove `response` and if there is other error modify your question.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using an object, instead of an array, and indexing by name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error, with a non existing variable called *response*, you need to delete it or declare it as a variable.

Then, your loop has a logic error, because you are checking the input values with each element of your array, and incrementing **entryCount** each time the data provided by user doesn't match with all of them. So, if I put let's say, **Ivan** as user, the entryCount will reach the limit with just one attempt. Also you are overwriting **bal** value.

A better way to do what you want is in the next code:

```
let entryCount = 0
let entryLimit = 3
let error = false

let validarCuentas = [
    { name: "Emilio", password: "abc123" },
    { name: "Andrea", password: "abc321" },
    { name: "Hugo", password: "contraseña" }
];

// Login with Attempts limit
function login() {
    let userInput = document.getElementById('user').value;
    let passInput = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    let balInput = document.getElementById('bal').value;

    let userFound = validarCuentas.find(user => user.name === userInput && user.password == passInput)

    if (userFound) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', userInput)
        localStorage.setItem('pass', passInput)
        localStorage.setItem('bal', balInput)
        window.location.href = "cajero.html"
    }
    else {
        alert('Contraseña o usuario invalido, intentelo nuevamente')
        entryCount++;
    } 
    
    if (entryCount >= entryLimit) {
        alert('Pasaste el limite de intentos')
        window.location.href = "index.html"
    }
  
    
}
```

In this way you take advantage of using find function of Array object and avoid to do an unnecessary loop. Also **entryCount** value was set to zero, because user has not done any attempt at the beginning.